# lose fingers and stuff (while?) trying to catch knives

Tags: phrase-meaning, usage

> ... like people in cooking school lose fingers and stuff trying to catch
>   knives.

Here is the context https://youtu.be/HkKRWOMMSs8?t=479

Could the sentence be interpreted as

> ... like people in cooking school lose fingers and stuff **while** trying to catch
>   knives.

?

Comment: Yes, that is what is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could. 'When' would also be a valid alternative.

Both 'when' and 'while' can be omitted only if it is clear who or what the modifying phrase refers to.

In your sentence, 'while' or 'when' is omitted since "trying to catch knives" can be attributed to "people in cooking school". However, this relies somewhat on common sense, since syntactically it could be argued that it is the "stuff" that is trying to catch knives.

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214378/omitting-while) presents the perils of omitting 'while' where context (or lack thereof) doesn't allow for easy understanding of the meaning.

Comment: If it was "when", should it be _"... like people in cooking school lose fingers and stuff when they try to catch knives"_ or _"... like people in cooking school lose fingers and stuff when they are trying to catch knives"_?

Comment: Both of those options work, and as I mentioned, so does 'when trying'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, the thread you mentioned is very helpful.